# PHP Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given

Tags: php

```
public function InitButton($Name, $Group, $T=0, $L=0, $W=1, $H=1, $BStyle=null, $Text='', $Expire = 0, $Repeat=true)
{
    $OldButton = ButtonManager::getButtonForKey($this->UCID, $Name);

    //Line 4 below: 
    if(get_class($OldButton) == 'Button') {

        $Button = $OldButton;
    } else {
        $Button = new Button($this->UCID, $Name, $Group);
    }
    $Button->T($T)->L($L)->W($W)->H($H);
    $Button->BStyle($BStyle);
    if(is_array($Text)) {
        $Button->Text($Text[0]);
        $this->bTexts[$Name] = $Text;
    } else {
        $Button->Text($Text);
        $this->bTexts[$Name][0] = $Text;
    }
    $Button->Send();

    $this->bState[$Name]['ID'] = 0;
    $this->bState[$Name]['timestamp'] = time() - 1;
    $this->bState[$Name]['override'] = false;
    if($Expire > 0) {
        $this->bState[$Name]['expire'] = time() + $Expire;
    } else {
        $this->bState[$Name]['expire'] = -1;
    }
    $this->bState[$Name]['repeatText'] = $Repeat;

}
```

PHP Warning:  get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given in C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test\test.php on line 4

How do i fix this?

Comment: $OldButton is null not an object. Test with a var_dump().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means that `ButtonManager::getButtonForKey($this->UCID, $Name);` returns `null`. If this is expected behavior perhaps change the if-statement to

```
if ($OldButton && get_class($OldButton) == 'Button')
```

this checks to see if the button is not null and then if the class is `'Button'`

If it is not expected behavior, something is going wrong in `ButtonManager`

Comment: Thank you. This fixed it

Comment: if it did could you mark it as solved please. This way future visitors can immediately find the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that `$OldButton` can be `null`, and you can't call `get_class` on a `null` value. Apparently, `ButtonManager::getButtonForKey($this->UCID, $Name)` can return `null`, and that's your problem. You could fix it by doing this before line 4:

```
if (!is_null($OldButton)) {
    if(get_class($OldButton) == 'Button') {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: quick note, while this code would work I recommend you check for `null` and throw and error instead of checking for not `null`. This makes your code more readable.